# In-app purchases - getting different developer payload

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I've implemented an in-app purchases functionality into my app as described in the following [link](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html).

The purchases made are for subscriptions (non consumable products). I've defined a test user in the Google Play Developer Console as described [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases) in order to complete a test purchase flow without any real payment.

Im testing my code with the same 2 real subscriptions, cancelling them upon each purchase completion in order to be able to purchase it again (when testing a flow again). Everything works great.

But...

I started to notice that im getting the same developer payload when calling

```
final String developerPayload = "xxxxxxx";   
mHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow(activity, sku.getSku() , 10001, new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() { 
       @Override
       public void onIabPurchaseFinished(final IabResult result, final Purchase info) {
          if (!verifyPayload(info, developerPayload)) {
             return;
          }
       }
    }, developerPayload);
```

even when the payload sent is completely different. What can be the reason ?
The only thing i can think of is that the subscription is not really cancelled for the test user im using. but why is that ?

The way im cancelling is by going to the Google Play Store app --> My apps --> Subscription tab.

appreciate any help.